# Does "injection drug use" always imply the use of illegal drugs?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From a [news report](http://www.mdmag.com/conference-coverage/croi-2018/patients-with-hiv-six-times-as-likely-to-have-shizophrenia):

> Among those with both HIV and schizophrenia, the population was mostly male (75%), living in an urban setting (91%), had a history of **injection drug use** (75%), and was at least once on anti-psychotic medication (49%; P <0.001). The population of patients with schizophrenia, but not HIV, reported lesser rates for **injection drug use** (20%) and antipsychotic medication (39%).

I'm unsure whether they mean "the use of illicit (narcotic) drugs" or just "the use of any active substances, including therapeutic, via the injection route". Is there a way to tell? I failed to find the study on PubMed and found only [the PDF of the poster](http://cfenet.ubc.ca/sites/default/files/uploads/croi2018/894-Closson_K-Rates_of_All-Cause_and_Accident-specific_Mortality_among_Schizophrenic_people_living_with_and_without_HIV.pdf) presented at a conference, which fails to clarify the issue.

Comment: I suppose they are discriminating from drug use by means of snorting, smoking or suppository application, none of which will be relevant in the context of HIV transference. In context, the statement seems to mean illicit narcotics. It is unlikely to refer to, for example, diabetic persons injecting insulin, though it could do.

Comment: Yeah, in that context one would assume that the reference is to "illicit" drugs.  But in other contexts this would not be the case.  And, absent some definitions, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Shouldn't they have used "intravenous drug use" anyway?

Comment: @n00dles not necessarily. Intramuscular injections are also possible (and I believe are used in illicit steroid use)

Comment: @ChrisH Oh shit, I'm with it now. HIV - needles. I just woke up! So by context it means any illicit injections, really.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your quote from MDmag, I suppose they are discriminating from drug use by means of snorting, smoking or suppository application, none of which will be relevant in the context of HIV transference. In context, the statement seems to mean illicit narcotics. It is unlikely to refer to, for example, diabetic persons injecting insulin, though it could do.

[AidsInfo](https://aidsinfo.nih.gov/understanding-hiv-aids/glossary/1585/injection-drug-use) uses the term 'injection drug use' - again, in context - to mean the injection of illicit drugs.

> A method of illicit drug use. The drugs are injected directly into the body

Comment: In medical contexts, "injection drug use" implies illicit, generally, and almost exclusively, heroin. However, target populations might have some variability, such as testosterone in the transgendered population.

Comment: @StuW, I disagree that it means heroin exclusively. Did you read that somewhere? If it's true that's ridiculous. Why would they discount all other common intravenous illicit drugs? That's stupid.

Comment: @StuW Absolute rubbish. Surely you’ve heard of an epipen. Or the old way. What about depo provera? Neuroleptic? Anaesthesia. Many other examples abound. You’re 100% wrong. Unless of course you want to argue semantics. But define ‘use’. It’s absurd.

Comment: Btw neuroleptic = antipsychotic. Should have been more specific. But I hear people refer to ‘using their epipen’ for example.

Comment: The point is not the word injection, but the phrase "drug use" which is widely used to mean illicit drug use. Medical professionals do not say "drug use" when referring to taking prescription medications.

Comment: BTW, snorting is pretty much relevant in the context of blood-borne deceases transmission, though not specifically HIV.

Comment: @barbecue medical professionals do say "drug use" to cover all of prescription, OTC and illegal drugs in contexts where it isn't relevant which of them is the case. When it not being prescribed is relevant it's more often called "recreational drug use" unless legal status actually has a bearing (e.g. when considering the cost/benefit of decriminalisation, needle exchanges, etc.)

Comment: @JonHanna Obviously some individuals may use any sorts of terminology. But doctors and nurses in hospitals do not say "did the patient use his drugs?" They say "Did the patient take his meds?" "Is Bob using drugs?" simply does not mean the same thing as  "Is bob taking his prescriptions as he ought to?"

Comment: @barbecue Good point. In common usage 'drugs' means 'illicit drugs'. The general populace would not admit to 'using drugs' but to 'taking medicine' etc, as you point out.

Comment: @barbecue why would they use that terminology where they want to cover all of prescribed, otc and recreational?

Comment: @JonHanna I'm not sure why you think that there needs to be a specific single term that covers all of those cases. My doctor knows I take prescription medication, and when she asked me "any drug use?" she and I both knew we're NOT talking about prescription or over the counter medications. I suppose if I needed to cover all bases I'd probably say something like "Are you taking any drugs, legal or otherwise?" or something along those lines. But that really does not come up often.

Comment: @barbecue I'm not sure why you think I think that.

Answer (score 8):

I expect that the term "use" implies "non-prescription" -- that phrases like "Are you a drug-user?" and "Have you ever used drugs?" would IMO never be used to refer to prescribed medications.

The linked PDF mentions "substance use disorder" which implies that meaning of the word "use".

Also I'd expect that clinical injections needn't correlate with blood-borne disease like HIV, whereas injection drug abuse is correlated because (so I've read) people unsafely share and reuse needles.

I think you're right that it is (or might seem) ambiguous or ill-defined, but I'd assume it means (or I think it implies) illegal drug abuse ... so much so that if they had meant to include "therapeutic" they'd have said so explicitly.

Comment: +1. I think the key distinction here is that the phrase "drug use" implies illicit drugs, and the "injection" is just a modifier in context.

Comment: Yeah, that's a really good point.

Comment: Depends on context even then. I am not female but I have known a woman who said she used Depo provera (I.e. completely legal).  Same with he/she had to use his epipen.

Comment: Drug user perhaps is another matter... but it still arguably makes an assumption. And the question quotes examples.

Comment: @Pryftan You can "use" a condom too -- i.e. Depo is a drug of choice, even if it is prescribed. There are (pretty few -- only 9000) [Google results for "insulin user"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22insulin+user%22) so  yes it's theoretically ambiguous -- and writing "abuse" rather than "use" is clearer -- I still think it's pretty clear in context.

Comment: Abuse yes that’s much better. Exactly because it removes ambiguity and removes assumptions. Then again we could argue that’s also semantics if we wanted to be silly. The beauty of languages I guess. Not sure your first point is relevant unless to extend my point (which maybe you are doing?).

Comment: Regardless of what we might prefer, the terms "drug use" and "using drugs" are widely known to refer to illicit drug use and are NOT commonly used to describe the taking of prescribed medicines.  Drugs are bad, meds are good. That's now the terminology is used. Doesn't matter if you like it or not.